# Isabelle: inconsistent functions for datatype

Tags: isabelle

The following Isabelle theory:

```
theory Example
  imports "HOL-Nominal.Nominal" 
begin

atom_decl vrs

nominal_datatype ty = 
    A
  | B "ty" 
  | C "ty"

nominal_primrec
  cv dv :: "ty ⇒ vrs list"
where
  "cv A = []"
| "cv (B T) = dv T"
| "cv (C T) = cv T"
| "dv A = []"
| "dv (B T) = cv T"
| "dv (C T) = dv T"

end
```

fails with the error:

> Nominal primrec definition error:
>   inconsistent functions for datatype "Example.ty"
>   in
>   "cv (B T) = dv T"

If one removes nominality one gets the error:

> "ty" is neither mutually recursive with "ty" nor nested recursive through itself

Does anybody know the meaning of these error messages? Any hints to solve them?

Comment: I am not very knowledgeable on the matter of the internals of `primrec`, but `fun` should work with the standard `datatype` for your use case (is there a reason why you need to use `primrec` specifically?). As far as Nominal goes, I never used it. However, Nominal2's `nominal_datatype`+`nominal_function` work for your use case.

Comment: @user9716869 thanks for trying those out for me